# Why does this give a precompile error that this dictionary class does not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Why does this give a precompile error that this dictionary class does not exist in current context?

[image: [IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/programming/doesnotexistincontext.png[/IMG]]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image; post it as text formatted as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. The variable is named `levelContent` not `levelcontent`.

Answer (score 2):

C# is case sensitive

```
 levelcontent != levelContent
```